# How can I get rid of this extra level of indirection?

Tags: c++, casting

I'd like to get rid of this extra level of indirection as it will be performance-critical. Specifically the array called 'componentPoolsArray[8]', it stores pointers that point to dynamically allocated pools. I'd like to build pool objects directly into the array, but they will be pool objects of different types. They will only be different by the type of internal pointer stored by the vector, not different in size, which is why I think I could cast or something:

```
struct HomogenousComponentPoolBaseClass {};

template <typename T_Component>
struct HomogenousComponentPool : HomogenousComponentPoolBaseClass
{
    std::vector<T_Component> componentPool;
};

struct ComponentTypeA { int component_A_Member; };
struct ComponentTypeB { int component_B_Member; };
struct ComponentTypeC { int component_C_Member; };

HomogenousComponentPoolBaseClass* componentPoolsArray[8]; // Pointers to component pools, will be heap-allocated
// The only reason I used inheritance here is so I could get it to compile by
// declaring pointers to a base class


int main()
{
    // Create new pool of ComponentTypeA
    componentPoolsArray[0] = new HomogenousComponentPool<ComponentTypeA>;

    // Create a new component in that pool
    static_cast<HomogenousComponentPool<ComponentTypeA>*>
        (componentPoolsArray[0])->componentPool.push_back(ComponentTypeA());

    // Access the first component object from that pool
    static_cast<HomogenousComponentPool<ComponentTypeA>*>
        (componentPoolsArray[0])->componentPool[0].component_A_Member;
}
```

So I'd like to build 'class HomogenousComponentPool<T_Component>' directly into 'componentPoolsArray[0]'. The way I see it I can do that a number of ways, but I'm not sure which is best or even if any are safe:

```
template <typename T_Component>
struct HomogenousComponentPool // No inheritance
{
    std::vector<T_Component> componentPool;
};

struct ComponentTypeA { int component_A_Member; };
struct ComponentTypeB { int component_B_Member; };

HomogenousComponentPool<char> componentPoolsArray[8]; // The class is built directly into the array.
        // Here I've selected 'char' as the template type, which means that HomogenousComponentPool
// will have std::vector<char> as the componentPool. Since the vector should only store pointers
// then I figured casting to another type won't matter.



int main()
{
    // Create new pool of ComponentTypeA directly into array
    componentPoolsArray[0] = HomogenousComponentPool<char>();

    // Create a new component in that pool
    // I can either cast the outside class
    reinterpret_cast<HomogenousComponentPool<ComponentTypeA>&>
        (componentPoolsArray[0]).componentPool.push_back(ComponentTypeA());
    // Or the inside std::vector
    reinterpret_cast<std::vector<ComponentTypeA>&>(componentPoolsArray[0].componentPool).push_back(ComponentTypeA());
    
}
```

Is this legal code? I thought about using a couple of methods including void pointers but I don't know how I can do this safely. I would only be doing this if the performance was really important

Comment: Not to jump on an 8,000+ rep user here, but... did you do any performance testing on the app to be sure that this is where optimization is needed?  Sometimes premature optimization really _is_ the root of all evil.

Comment: This feels like premature optimization.  If you care about perf this much, I am betting you can save much more than a pointer indirection using other techniques.  But let's say you are writing code so fast that an extra indirection is actually tanking perf.  In cases like that, sometimes you just have to break type safety.  Not that big of a deal IMO as long as it's well encapsulated so the `void*` doesn't leak outside of the immediate area it's needed.  Memory allocators commonly hold memory as arrays of `unsigned char` and cast to the proper type as needed.

Comment: The second way is not safe. A `vector<char>` is not a `vector<something_else>`. (While in practice it _probably_ works, there is no guarantee. You also have to manually clean up the vector.) What would work better may be to use a union, either a vector of unions or a union of vectors (which is sorta what your second way is trying to do, but it would then be using proper support of the language).

Comment: It may be worth looking at [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 Only the second one? But the first cast is casting a T<char> to a T<ComponentTypeA>, it also isn't the class type I cast it as. There's a difference with std::vector? The thing is that if I cast the outer class instead of the std::vector the compiler will treat that std::vector<char> as std::vector<something_else> anyway, no?